# scala - error: ')' expected but '(' found

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and I cannot find out what is causing this error, I have searched similar topics but unfortunately, none of them worked for me. I've got a simple code to find the line from some README.md file with the most words in it. The code I wrote is:

```
    val readme = sc.textFile("/PATH/TO/README.md")
    readme.map(lambda line :len(line.split())).reduce(lambda a, b: a if (a > b) else b)
```

and the error is:

```
    Name: Compile Error
    Message: <console>:1: error: ')' expected but '(' found.
    readme.map(lambda line :len(line.split()) ).reduce( lambda a, b: a                 
    if (a > b) else b )        ^

    <console>:1: error: ';' expected but ')' found.
    readme.map(lambda line :len(line.split()) ).reduce( lambda a, b: a 
    if (a > b) else b )                       ^
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it has nothing in common with the Scala syntax

Comment: To be honest this question looks trollish.

Comment: Not every language is Python. There are different languages and Scala is one of those. If you want to use Scala - learn Scala syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't valid *Scala*.

I think what you might be trying to do is to determine the largest number of words on a single line in a *README* file using *Spark*. Is that right? If so, then you likely want something like this:

```
val readme = sc.textFile("/PATH/TO/README.md")
readme.map(_.split(' ').length).reduce(Math.max)
```

That last line uses some argument abbreviations. This alternative version is equivalent, but a little more explicit:

```
readme.map(line => line.split(' ').length).reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))
```

The `map` function converts an `RDD` of `String`s (each line in the file) into an `RDD` of `Int`s (the number of words on a single line, delimited - in this particular case - by spaces). The `reduce` function then returns the largest value of its two arguments - which will ultimately result in a single `Int` value representing the largest number of elements on a single line of the file.

After re-reading your question, it seems that you might want to know the line with the most words, rather than how many words are present. That's a little trickier, but this should do the trick:

```
readme.map(line => (line.split(' ').length, line)).reduce((a, b) => if(a._1 > b._1) a else b)._2
```

Now `map` creates an `RDD` of a *tuple* of `(Int, String)`, where the first value is the number of words on the line, and the second is the line itself. `reduce` then retains whichever of its two tuple arguments has the larger integer value (`._1` refers to the first element of the tuple). Since the result is a tuple, we then use `._2` to retrieve the corresponding line (the second element of the tuple).

I'd recommend you read a good book on *Scala*, such as *Programming in Scala, 3rd Edition*, by Odersky, Spoon & Venners. There's also some [tutorials and an overview of the language](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html) on the main [*Scala* language site](https://scala-lang.org). *[Coursera](https://coursera.org/)* also has some free *Scala* training courses that you might want to sign up for.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt or `readme.map(_.split(' ').length).max` which uses a lot less memory/storage. I was just relating my answer to his question. ;-)